# Determine the height of a $3D$ trigonometry problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The question is

Jamie is surveying a cliff to determine the elevation from the base of a canyon to the top of the cliff. She lays out a line $AB$ that is $225 m$ in length. She also sites a point $C$ at the base of the cliff. Point $D$ is a point directly above point $C$, at the top of the cliff. She measures  to be $43°$,  to be $58°$, and the angle of elevation from point $A$ to point $D$ to be $29°$.

> 1. Draw a diagram to model this situation.
> 2. Determine the height of the cliff.

Here's my model

[image]

What I did to measure to find C:

1. $C: 180-43-58 = 79°$

This is where I'm stuck. I don't really know where to go.

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On my screen, the height of the problem is about 11 inches.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{AC}{sinB}=\frac{AB}{sinC}$$ $$AC=\frac{ABsin58}{sin79}$$ $$AD=\frac{AC}{cos29}=\frac{ABsin58}{sin79cos29}$$ $$DC=ADcos(ADC)=\frac{ABsin58cos61}{sin79cos29}=\frac{225sin58cos61}{sin79cos29}\approx107.75 m$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Use [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) and Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @Taylor Swift No response to the answer above?